Which OS supported for Alexa MAX-toolkit? https://github.com/alexa/max-toolkit
I have not found any documents mentioned the OS supported for Alexa MAX-toolkit.
Could you please help to provide some info?
https://github.com/alexa/max-toolkit

In the same repo there is a directory which exlains the pre-requisites. It is suppported on Ubuntu and Mac OS

Seems that it describe to support build one Ubuntu & MacOS.
I means on which OS can max-toolkit run? such as, can it support yocto linux?

Typo above comments "Seems that it describe to support build on Ubuntu & MacOS. I means on which OS can max-toolkit run? such as, can it support yocto linux?"
